# Best way to collect data for an iPad app that also have an offline mode

Tags: ios, ipad, offline

My client states in an iPad app brief that the data (i.e. products and images) must be taken from an online source and saved. However, the app must also have an offline mode which shows this same data from when the app was previously online for times when internet access is not available (kind of like an offline reader). What would be the best way to tackle this? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the data when the device is online and store it locally using whatever mechanism seems most appropriate (SQLite, Core Data, property lists, your own file format, etc.). Use this cached data when offline, and when online too unless it has changed. Create some mechanism that you can use to detect and download updates (preferably just the changes) when online.

This will be a big help for your users not just when they're offline, but online too. 3G data plans for the iPad are usually limited, so the better you can avoid repeat downloads of large resources like images, the better for your users.

Comment: be sure to not forget the backup-flags for ios 5+ iCloud storage.